# Select Data At every 3 minutes from starting timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I want to select data from table at every 3 minutes interval from the starting timestamp using postgresql.

```
31-12-2015 10:00:00
31-12-2015 10:01:00
31-12-2015 10:02:00
31-12-2015 10:03:00
31-12-2015 10:04:00
31-12-2015 10:05:00
```

Required Output is

```
31-12-2015 10:00:00
31-12-2015 10:03:00
```

Comment: The answer will be the same but did you want to consider being consistent between "every 15 minutes" and "every 3 minutes"?

Comment: is these data in table like a column of "timestamp" contains these rows?

Comment: yes column of timestamp contains these rows

Comment: Edit your question, and include CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements. Also show what you tried, and how it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

With sample table

```
CREATE TABLE tm (tme TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO tm
VALUES ('31-12-2015 10:00:00')
    ,('31-12-2015 10:01:00')
    ,('31-12-2015 10:02:00')
    ,('31-12-2015 10:03:00')
    ,('31-12-2015 10:04:00')
    ,('31-12-2015 10:05:00');
```

and the select should be

```
SELECT *
FROM tm
WHERE to_char(tme, 'MI')::INT IN (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT to_char(tme, 'MI')::INT col
            FROM tm
            ) t
        WHERE mod(col, 3) = 0
        );
```

Simplified

```
select * 
from
tm where mod(to_char(tme, 'MI')::int,3)=0
```

result:

```
tme                 
------------------- 
2015-12-31 10:00:00 
2015-12-31 10:03:00
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e9ac7/2)

Comment: date_part('minutes', ((TIMESTAMP WITHOUT Time Zone 'epoch' + "TIMESTAMP_S" * INTERVAL '1 second') 
AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT Time Zone)::int % 3= 0 I am using this but the problem is when i am changing from 3 minutes to 15 mintues it is not showing 1st time stamp i.e 31-12-2015 10:00:00